# How to use decimal number in core-plot?

Tags: core-plot

I am trying to give float point into core-plot y axis value, it is not working. So is i need to give it as whole number instead of decimal number.If decimal number works please give me the sample code.

Comment: Please stop signing your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many axis properties take an NSDecimal value. Core Plot includes a number of utility functions to make it easier to create them. You can see examples of the usage throughout the example programs. Look for `CPDecimalFromDouble`, `CPDecimalFromFloat`, `CPDecimalFromString`, etc.

For the plot data, you can provide any `NSNumber` instance. Core Plot supports `NSDecimalNumber` as well and will use higher-precision calculations when drawing the graph, although this comes at a performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can make NSNUmber instance, then assign with NSDecimalNumber value. For example:

```
NSNumber *tmpNum = nil;
tmpNum = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:yourFloat] decimalVaue]];
```